# VBA Excel: How to edit links using user cell inputs?

Tags: excel, replace, vba

I'm trying to make a macro that, among other things, updates external file links in several cells, where the file location currently in the cells and that which I want to change it to are specified by the user in another tab.

I've tried to do this via find/replace; if I try to do this with the text specified in the code:

```
Range("b3").Formula = Replace(Range("B3").Formula, "\\folder\file", "\\folder\newfile")
```

Then it'll replace this text and the links update correctly. If I change the locations with inputs, say *oldlocation* and *newlocation*:

```
oldlocation= "\\folder\file"
newlocation= "\\folder\newfile"

Range("b3").Formula = Replace(Range("B3").Formula, oldlocation, newlocation)
```

This also works ok. But if I change the definitions of the locations (e.g. B3: "\folder\file"):

```
oldlocation= Range("b3").text
newlocation= Range("b4").text
```

It no longer works - passes over the line in the code with no change or error. I've made a quick check and *Range("b3").text* & *"\folder\file"* both seem to be text strings; after that I'm stumped. I've tried a few different find/replace formats I've found, but all with the same result. What am I missing?

Comment: Try adding a Debug.Print oldlocation,newlocation before the replace command to see what you're actually reading.  Maybe try .value instead of .text?  You can use the str() function to cast it as a string if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you define the string to be replaced as

```
  oldlocation= Range("b3").text
```

the `oldlocation` variable will have the value of the cell (the data you see in the cell) not the formula of the cell that contains the current reference, so the replace function does not find the string to be replaced.
You have to extract the location that you want to replace from the `Range("b3").formula` string and work with that.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please mark the answer a solution for other people!